# Do you need a CDF player if you already have a Mathematica Desktop?

Tags: cdfplayer

Does CDF player have any privilege over Mathematica? Is is necessary to install CDF player if you already have Mathematica desktop version installed?

Comment: If the CDF's are only for your use on the machine that you have *Mathematica*, then probably not.  However, if you intend to share a CDF with someone else who only has the CDF Player, then you should install the CDF Player to test your CDF.  That's because not all *Mathematica* features are available with the CDF Player.

Comment: This is a tricky question, I need it to test if my CDFs are working correctly on player, before I send them further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely not. Everything CDF Player can do Mathematica can do, but then Mathematica's got a lot more as well. They are both (relatively) large files, so I would certainly recommend only have Mathematica installed. [This table](https://www.wolfram.com/player-pro/how-player-pro-compares.html) is fairly informative.